# Exit series of nested call backs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, callback

In the following code when an `err` variable is returned from the callback function of `deleteUser` I want to insert the error into the database and end the HTTP request (and this entire code block) with `return res.send(500)`.

Instead the code continues running and `db.destroy` is called, even though the HTTP request has already ended. This is evidenced by the logs at the bottom of the post.

```
// DELETE
app.del('/api/users', function(req, res) {
    var id = req.query.id;

    // get latest copy of database entry first, in case we need to save error message
    db.get(id, {revs_info: true}, function(err, doc) {
        if (err) {
            console.error('Unable to find document', id, 'due to:', err);
            return res.send(500);
        } else {
            // issue delete request first, if fails save error message
            deleteUser(doc.EmailAddress, function(err) {
                if (err) {
                    // update database with error message (if there's already a message, append)
                    doc.Notes = (doc.Notes === '') ? err : err + " " + doc.Notes;

                    db.insert(doc, function(err, document) {
                        if(err) {
                            console.error('Deleting a user failed (1) and updating database with error status failed (2) as well. 1:', doc.Notes, '2:', err);
                            return res.send(500);
                        } else {
                            console.error('Deleting a user failed (with the following) and the error has been stored in the database:', doc.Notes);
                            return res.send(500);
                        }
                    });
                }

                // proceed to delete from database as well
                db.destroy(doc._id, doc._rev, function (err, body) {
                    if(err) {
                        console.error('Error deleting document', doc._id, 'with:', err);
                        return res.send(500);
                    } else {
                        if (doc._revs_info) delete doc._revs_info;
                        console.log('Succesfully deleted user from system and our database:', doc);
                        return res.send(200);
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    });
});
```

I assume this is happening because my `return` statement only ends the `db.insert` function.

Is there a common design pattern for solving this problem in node?

Should I simply add another `return` statement after the `db.insert` declaration but before ending the `if (err) {` code block?

Logs after issuing the DELETE request to my server instance:

```
Deleting a user failed (with the following) and the error has been stored in the database: POST 500 has returned an error.

127.0.0.1 - - [Mon, 19 Oct 2015 02:50:19 GMT] "DELETE /api/users?id=11 HTTP/1.1" 500 21 "http://localhost:3000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Fedora; Linux x86_64; rv:41.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/41.0"

Succesfully deleted user from system and our database: { _id: '11',
  _rev: '3-e6fec584448d664476ddaf3b7e150cd7',
  EmailAddress: 'testuser@xyz.com',
  Status: 0,
  Notes: 'POST 500 has returned an error.' }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, **yes**, add a `return` statement before you close the `if() {}`. That's crucial.

Second, your code suffers from [callback hell](http://callbackhell.com/), and you should seriously consider switching to a more "modern" alternative, my personal favorite is promises. [Here's a great article about this](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/).

For node, try looking at [bluebird](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bluebird) or [es6-promisify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/es6-promisify)

Answer (score 0):

You could introduce an error flag somewhere high which defaults to false:

```
var bFatalError = false;
```

Anywhere that you've detected a fatal error you set this flag before returning:

```
bFatalError = true;
```

And at the top of each block of code you can test-and-abort if the flag is set:

```
if (bFatalError) { return; }
```

In this way, you're signaling the other code not to start.